# Specific handling for an additional 3rd file upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

previously I created a form with a couple of file uploads, it works Ok, but now I´ve been asked to add a 3rd file upload, the field for this 3rd upload appears dynamically as result of a specific option in a select existing in the form, only for one of its options the 3rd upload appears, that´s Ok, no problem, but, the requirement for this 3rd file is that it must be a CSV file, how do I handle its type when what I had (in the form controller) for the other two files is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize(array(
                "upload_path" => "uploads/",
                "overwrite" => TRUE,
                "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
                "allowed_types" => "txt|pdf|gif|jpg|png|tiff|doc|docx|rtf|jpeg",
                "max_size" => 1024*2048,
                "max_width"=> 1024,
                "max_height"=> 768,
                "xss_clean" => FALSE
            )); 

            foreach($_FILES as $field => $file){
                if($file['error'] == 0){
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload($field)){
                        $data = $this->upload->data();
                        array_push($arreglo, $data['file_name']);
                        echo ($data['file_name']);
                    }else{
                        $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    }
                }
            }                        
        }
```

and their corresponding validation rules; what´s different in this 3rd file is that it is a CSV file, when the other two are graphic or usual document type, and no other type than CSV should be accepted as the 3rd upload,

Answer (score 0):

(Actually half) Solved!  when you upload files, the $_FILES superglobal generates entries for each of those files, even if you don´t upload them, so, echoing `$field`, I found I can use that key to assign file types as follows:

```
foreach($_FILES as $field => $file){
         if($field != "file3"){
                $config["allowed_types"] = "txt|pdf|gif|jpg|png|tiff|doc|docx|rtf|jpeg";
         }else{
            $config["allowed_types"] = "csv";
         }
 }
```

Tested using a graphic file as the 3rd upload, it just didn´t upload! and if you use a csv file, it uploads with no problem :D

Post Edit: actually half solved, that for each switches the file type, if there´s a 3rd upload, it switches to csv type, if not, it keeps graphic/regular document type, any ideas? thanx i.a.

Final edit and solution: you just have to upload each file, one by one and setting the same config with different rules in each case, if you want to read about it, I found it here, thanks to his author!
[multiple file upload with multiple config in codeigniter](http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/multiple-file-uploads-using-codeigniter)